# Lookup value of dict based on model

Tags: python, django

I have a dictionary - returned from rest. It presents a UUID

Inside my template i need to display the list returned but want to find the UUID value from a row in model e.g.

[{'value1': 'somevalue', 'id':'04fca561-ef45-47d3-a1f3-617e7f24961d'}{'value1': 'somevalue', 'id':'04fca561-ef45-47d3-b2e4-617e7f24961d'}]

In my model i have a field such as :

mykeyvalue = models.ForeignKey(SOmeotherModel, on_delete=...)

I can use the {%for value in list%} {{value.id}}{%endfor} successfully. but i want to display the meaningful value such that it get it from the model. Hope this makes sense.

I thought about making a new dictionary up using loops.

What is the best way around this issue.

Comment: use `dict.items()` in a for loop and make a test for `id`

Answer (score 1):

you can iterate over list and create a new list from your model objects then pass them to your template:

```
objects = []
for key, val in your_list.items():
    objects.append(Model.objects.get(id=val)) # you should handle error when object is not found
```